# Getting next page data through selenium and request

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm looking to click on the next page to get the listed product data:  https://www.riteaid.com/shop/grocery

When I look at the HTML element, the Next button is actually not a button element, but a span tag. Looking at the developer tools, I noticed that there is a  tag that dynamically changes when I click on the next button without moving to a different url.

```
<div data-pager="p:pg1" data-tp="89" data-cp="2">
```

How would one go about getting the next page data or send the request to get the next page data? I thought I'd need selenium since it is interactive, but I got the error "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke click onto the element.

```
driver.get("https://www.riteaid.com/shop/grocery")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Next']/parent::div")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks Arundeep. This did the trick! Can you help me understand what's going on in these commands based on how the content is loaded? I tried checking the network tab to see if it was making any requests, but I wasn't able to see any obvious interactions where the data was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the site and you can navigate to next page like this:

```
next_page_xpath = "//div[@class='rfk_next']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_page_xpath).click()
```

Do remember to do while and put above code in try/except, so that it breaks from while loop once there will be no next page.

Comment: I get the following error when I tried this:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Is there something else that I am missing?